# Why there are Discrepancies in SonarQube Results?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops

There are discrepancies in SonarQube results. We are using two Jenkins pipeline one is Freestyle and the other one is Pipeline as code. But there is a difference in bugs reported by both. Can anyone tell me why?

We are getting one extra bug in Pipeline as code. There is also a difference in the number of properties we are passing.

In Pipeline as Code we are passing : -Dsonar.projectKey, -Dsonar.projectName, -Dsonar.language, -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths

In Freestyle pipeline we are passing : sonar.login, sonar.projectKey, sonar.sources, sonar.java.binaries, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.tests, sonar.java.coveragePlugin, sonar.jacoco.reportPaths

Can anyone tell me what could be the possible reasons behind it?

Comment: what is the additional bug and which location/file is it reported on. Most likely it is because of sonar.sources property - that defines which all files sonar will consider for scanning.

Comment: There is only one bug in the pipeline as code no other. And files that are being scanned are the same. One scan showing the bug and the other does not.

Comment: Please add both the sonar logs from both scans.